# Unidentified constant value

Tags: arduino-uno, compile, mathematics

im working on the following project [kalman filter](https://github.com/har-in-air/Kalmanfilter_altimeter_vario)

and im working to implement in arduino.. i read the entire code and i succesfully implemented it into arduino but i couldnt implement the following function [code line](https://github.com/har-in-air/Kalmanfilter_altimeter_vario/blob/master/Usage.txt#L28) because arduino gives "not defined" error in **PI_DIV_180**

```
imu_MadgwickQuaternionUpdate(bUseAccel,elapsedTimeSecs,fax,fay,faz,fgx*PI_DIV_180,fgy*PI_DIV_180,fgz*PI_DIV_180,fmx,fmy,fmz);
```

it multiplies `fgx` with **PI_DIV_180** but as i said arduino cant identify it

i looked into math.h to find the value of that define but there isnt anything in math.h related with this

the `imu_MadgwickQuaternionUpdate` function is in here **IMU.cpp**

can anyone help me please thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's pi (π) divided by 180?

Pi is roughly: 3.1415926535898

So:

```
3.1415926535898 / 180 = 0.017453292519943
```

So add this line:

```
#define PI_DIV_180 0.017453292519943
```

Comment: yeah it may be...will try it..thanx